# Text animation similar to carousel animating too far

Tags: html, css, animation

I found an animation on codepen that I am interested in replicating but the words animate too far. I had a carousel that had a similar issue and adding...

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

...fixed it. However adding that breaks the animation worse in this case, even when I add 0 margins and paddings to everything except for the ones used in the example.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7z72s04/)

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='visible'>
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>world !</li>
      <li>Bob !</li>
      <li>users !</li>
      <li>everybody !</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line is too long. The exclamation mark wraps to the next line. This makes the text content 5 lines long, which is still animated as if it were 4 lines, so each animation step shifts 1.25 times the line height.

I suggest adding `ul {white-space: nowrap;}`. This will force each line to be on a single line. The box will grow wider, if necessary, if the text doesn't fit.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7z72s04/2/)